# Is support coming for UWP (specifically Hololens 2) for Agora RTC?

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, webrtc, hololens, agora.io

I am developing a cross platform AR app for Hololens and Mobile and need to stream the composited AR view from the device. I am using agora for my Android and iOS apps and it works well but can't find anything on whether Agora will support UWP.
If not is there a recommended alternative that will work on the Hololens 2?

Comment: How about asking the maker of that library?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC on the Hololens?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this Agora community SDK for UWP platform: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/AgoraUWP